# using $sub inside $inc with references to collection fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

```
updateLastDiscount(orderId, lastDiscount) {
        return Order.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": orderId},
            {
                $set: {
                    "last_discount": lastDiscount,
                },
                $inc: {
                    "total_discount": { $subtract: [ lastDiscount, "$last_discount" ] },
                }
            });
    }
```

I'm trying to increase (or decrease) **total_discount** by the subtraction of the old and new value of last_discount field.
I get the error *CastError: Cast to Number failed for value "[ 90, '$last_discount' ]" (type Array) at path "total_discount".*
Isn't it possible to reference the current value of a fields to update another field's value like above?

Comment: try pipeline put set and int in array